# Casperjs intermittent "NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101"

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, casperjs

I'm using CasperJS `clientutils` module to send a synchronous AJAX request to a different site. It works almost all of the time, but sometimes I get the following error:

```
"Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101\n    at sendAJAX
```

The code is straightforward:

```
url = "https://mysite.com"
response = __utils__.sendAJAX(url, 'POST', {"data": data}, false)
```

I've seen a bunch of other posts about this issue, but in those cases, the error seems to occur consistently and not intermittently. Any idea why this would happen?